# Aurelia is emitting different css code in Foundation using a dropdown menu when compared to the same page when using the regular method

Tags: zurb-foundation, aurelia

> System Info:
>
> Windows 7 x64
>
> aurelia-framework: "^1.0.0-beta.1.1.3"
>
> "foundation-sites": "^6.2.1"
>
> skeleton-navigation-webpack

How do I get the css code emitted when using aurelia and foundation together to be the same as when using foundation alone in a standard web page?  This is causing the dropdown to work incorrectly.

I am using the skeleton-navigation-webpack and just substituting foundation html and css for nav-bar and a empty welcome page

Aurelia Code

main.js to initialize foundation framwork

```
 aurelia.start().then(a => a.setRoot('app', document.body))
    .then(a => {
      // Initialize any frameworks you want to use
       $(document).foundation();
      console.log('foundation loaded')
    });
```

The  initialization of foundation `$(document).foundation();`  seems to work as the dropdown menu is displayed and working but the css is slightly different

nav-bar.html snippet before code is emitted

```
      <ul class="menu" data-responsive-menu="drilldown medium-dropdown">
        <li class="has-submenu">
          <a href="#">One</a>
          <ul class="submenu menu vertical" data-submenu>
            <li repeat.for="row of router.navigation">
              <a href.bind="row.href">${row.title}</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
      </ul>
```

Importing the foundation css in Aurelian and link in standard html page. The only difference is in the html page in using the repeat.for for `<li>` via Aurelia

emitted code in Aurelia

```
<ul class="menu dropdown" data-responsive-menu="drilldown medium-dropdown" role="menubar" data-dropdown-menu="x96kho-dropdown-menu">
        <li class="has-submenu is-dropdown-submenu-parent opens-left" role="menuitem" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="One" data-is-click="false">
          <a href="#" tabindex="0">One</a>
          <ul class="submenu menu vertical is-dropdown-submenu first-sub" data-submenu="" aria-hidden="true" role="menu">
            <!--<view>--><li role="menuitem" class="is-submenu-item is-dropdown-submenu-item">
              <a href.bind="row.href" class="au-target" au-target-id="1" href="#/">Welcome</a>
            </li><!--</view>--><!--<view>-->
```

Standard html page

```
<ul class="menu dropdown" data-responsive-menu="drilldown medium-dropdown" role="menubar" data-dropdownmenu="nfmerw-dropdownmenu" data-responsivemenu="8q9bqc-responsivemenu">
      <li class="has-submenu is-dropdown-submenu-parent is-down-arrow is-active" role="menuitem" tabindex="0" title="One" aria-haspopup="true">
        <a href="#" tabindex="-1">One</a>
        <ul class="submenu menu vertical is-dropdown-submenu first-sub js-dropdown-active" data-submenu="" aria-hidden="false" tabindex="-1" role="menu">
          <li role="menuitem" class="is-submenu-item is-dropdown-submenu-item" tabindex="0"><a href="#" tabindex="-1">One</a></li>
```

One specific is the open-left class in the first `<li>`

```
   <li class="has-submenu is-dropdown-submenu-parent opens-left" role="menuitem" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="One" data-is-click="false">
```

Verse the is-down arrow is active

```
<li class="has-submenu is-dropdown-submenu-parent is-down-arrow is-active" role="menuitem" tabindex="0" title="One" aria-haspopup="true">
```

Comment: But what is the question? Do you want to know why, do you want to solve it, is one working better then the other?

Comment: randy, updated question to make it more clear as to what I am looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'reflow'` is not Foundation 6, I instead use

```
attached(){
  // refresh JS after DOM is loaded
  $(document).foundation();
}
```

I can't test if this works better helping you out on the different CSS, but I do know this is the new reflow.

Answer found here: [Foundation 6 & Reflow](http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/36272-foundation-6--reflow). I tested the reflow functionality, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Aurelia as a "Single Page Application" framework loads page content dynamically all the time. I don't have tested it, but I think you have to re-apply foundation after ajax content is loaded.

You can do it  calling foundation 'reflow' in the [attached view-model method](http://aurelia.io/docs.html#/aurelia/framework/1.0.0-beta.1.2.2/doc/article/creating-components):

```
attached()  {
  $(document).foundation();
}
```

Comment: Great suggestion! But I get foundation.js:294 Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: We're sorry, 'reflow' is not an available method for this element.(…).  I am adding the reflow to the nav-bar.js file attached callback.  I also tried Foundation.reInit('dropdown-menu'); since that seems to be reflow's replacement in foundation 6 but I still received a similar  error  foundation.js:130 ReferenceError: We're sorry, '_init' is not an available method for this element.(…)

Comment: Updated the answer: as randy says, in foundation 6 to reflow you simply call `$(document).foundation();`

Comment: yeah I tried that first but it said something like the components are already loaded

Comment: sorry but i can't help you... maybe [this link](http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/38051-foundation-6-reinitreset-a-plugin) could help. Also by [this other link](http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/39007-foundation-and-smoothstatejs) seems there are problems with  re-initialize foundation plugins

Comment: Thanks for the links, hopefully zurb will have a solution and that will fix it.